# Cakephp can't locate core helper: JqueryEngineHelper.php when on server

Tags: cakephp

When I run my app on my locale machine it works fine, but when I run it on my sever using cpanel, everything works fine expect when I use js helper using jquery library the following error occurs

> Error: jqueryEngineHelper could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class jqueryEngineHelper below in file:
>   app/View/Helper/jqueryEngineHelper.php

```
<?php
class jqueryEngineHelper extends AppHelper {

}
```

Nb: all the files exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's incorrectly looking for "jqueryEngineHelper" instead of "JqueryEngineHelper" which most likely means you didn't use correct casing when specifying the helper in controller. Make sure you have `public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));` with capital "J" for "Jquery" and not "jquery"

Comment: Wooow thank you , youre good ! , but why it worked on my localhost ?

Comment: Because locally you are using windows which has a case insensitive file system.

Comment: Welcome, you might want to select my answer as the accepted one :)

Answer (score -1):

Try with `App::uses()` to load the helper.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-classes

Example from CakePHP documentation:

```
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
```

You try:

```
App::uses('jqueryEngineHelper', 'View/Helper');
```

EDIT:

Try putting that in your **AppController.php** at your starting lines in your code.